# How does JavaScript interpret "i"

Tags: javascript, arrays, anonymous-function

I thought "i" in JavaScript was just a common name for the argument passed in an anonymous function. But in the online lesson I am taking right now, we use I in the following way:

```
var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

while(input !== "quit"){
    if(input === "list"){
        todos.forEach(function(todo, i){
            console.log(i + ": " + todo);
        });
    } else if(input === "new") {
        var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
        todos.push(newTodo);
    }  

    //run code again
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
}
console.log("Okay, you Quit the App");
```

What this is doing is in the Chrome Developer Console, it is logging my array items with their corresponding index numbers listed before them when I type in "list". My question is: *how does JavaScript know that "i" should pass in the index number?* I tested it out with a bunch of random argument names to replace "I" and it still knew to provide the index location...how does that work?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean the `i` in `todos.forEach(function(todo, i)`?  the second argument of the callback function is defined by the JavaScript standard to be the index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: `i` is still just a common name there. You can replace it with any other valid JS variable name and it will work the same.

Comment: note that the name of the variable doesn't affect how the program works (although it *is* important for humans to understand the code better) - it could have been called `a`, `z`, `myCrazyVariableName`, or whatever, just as well as `i`. But it holds the array index of the particular todo because that's what how the language defines [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the callback function passed to .forEach can have these arguments:

```
function callback ((element, index, arr), thisValue))
```

Only element is required rest are optional.
element is the element that we are iterating through in the array,
index is the index of that element in the array,
arr refers to the array that .forEach was called on,
thisValue refers to the value of this keyword that should be in the function.

so the i refers to the index we are currently at in the iteration.
Nothing special about the i it’s not a keyword or anything. It’s just because it’s the second argument in the callback function. I could have named it idx for that matter.